# PHP Reflection with two calls

Tags: php, reflection

I am trying to archive some reflection in php. How can i make something like that. With my code i am getting following error:

> Undefined property: A::$getB()->getStr()

```
class B{
    public function getStr(){
        return 'str';
    }
}
class A{
    public function getB(){
        return new B();
    }
}

$a = new A();
$method = 'getB()->getStr()';
echo($a->$method);
```

Comment: I dont think you can chain multiple object accessors like that inside a string. You need to call them with `$class->$methodName()->$subMethod()`

Comment: there is a language construct to achive this...it beginns with "e"...e...v...a...*whistles inocently* *runs*

Comment: you better run fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split the call chain to the single calls

```
$getB = "getB";
$str = "getStr";
$a = new A();
echo $a->$getB()->$str();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.reflectionclass.php) and [ReflectionMethod](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.reflectionmethod.php) instead of string wizardy.

Comment: sometimes this is just overkill, but thanks for the input.